# GCP: How to change VPC subnet region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-networking

I want to change VPC network subnet region of Google Cloud platform.
I did't find any documentation around this.

This is part of Disaster Recovery we want to do if any region goes down.

Any reference much appreciated.

Comment: Same issue. The region that I selected doesn't have an option for back up and dr service. How did you manage this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to move subnets between regions in GCP.  You can delete and recreate the subnet in a different region, but not move it.

Comment: Could you give more details? Do you need to delete all you vpc or you delete only one subnet? Where are located the option for recreate your subnet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the subnet to a different region in the same VPC, you delete the subnet, then recreate it in a different region.  For example, let's say you want to delete the 10.10.10.0/24 subnet from the us-east4 cloud region and recreate it in the us-west2 cloud region (all within the VPC named `vpc-1`):

```
 ~  gcloud compute networks subnets delete subnet-1 \
    --region=us-east4
The following subnetworks will be deleted:
 - [subnet-1] in [us-east4]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  

Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/zachseils-dev-206600/regions/us-east4/subnetworks/subnet-1].
 ~  
 ~  gcloud compute networks subnets create subnet-1 \
    --region=us-west2 \
    --network=vpc-1 \
    --range=10.10.10.0/24
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/zachseils-dev-206600/regions/us-west2/subnetworks/subnet-1].
NAME      REGION    NETWORK  RANGE          STACK_TYPE  IPV6_ACCESS_TYPE  INTERNAL_IPV6_PREFIX  EXTERNAL_IPV6_PREFIX
subnet-1  us-west2  vpc-1    10.10.10.0/24  IPV4_ONLY
```